# Using Row Data to Select Column Data From Separate Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, crosstab

I have data I need to reconcile from two different queries. This data comes from a person selecting the dates and payments to defer a loan. That information goes into a row in a table relating to query 1. The payments are not stored in the row in query 1. The payments are stored in a table in query 2. The only piece of data that relates the two data sources is the date. I need to in some way turn query 1 into a table from a row and then relate it to query 2 table. In this example, the customer wanted to defer the payments for February 29th and March 29th but NOT the April 29th payment.

## Query 1

```
SELECT   TOP(1)     task_detail.task_refno
, task_detail.userdef10
, task_detail.userdef11
, task_detail.userdef12
, task_detail.userdef13
, task_detail.userdef37
, task_detail.userdef38
, task_detail.userdef39
, task_detail.userdef40
FROM            task INNER JOIN
task_detail ON task.task_refno = task_detail.task_refno
WHERE        (task.NLS_refno = 53475)
ORDER BY task.task_refno DESC
```

## **Query 1 Results**

```
task_refno  userdef10   userdef11   userdef12   userdef13   userdef37   userdef38   userdef39   userdef40
252152      02/29/2020  03/30/2020   04/30/2020  NULL          1           1           0           0
```

## Query 2

```
SELECT TOP (6) lpd.row_id, lpd.date_due, lpd.payment_remaining
FROM                          loanacct_payments_due AS lpd INNER JOIN
                         loanacct AS la ON lpd.acctrefno = la.acctrefno
WHERE (lpd.date_due <= DATEADD(m, 3, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))) 
AND (lpd.payment_type = 'PB' OR
     lpd.payment_type = 'PI' OR
     lpd.payment_type = 'P' OR
     lpd.payment_type = 'I') 
AND la.acctrefno = 53475
```

## Query 2 Results

```
row_id  date_due                 payment_remaining
6924954 2020-02-29 00:00:00.000 388.97
6970925 2020-03-30 00:00:00.000 398.97
7015051 2020-04-30 00:00:00.000 408.97
```

Notice that in query 1 results userdef10, userdef11, userdef12, userdef13 relate to the date_due in query 2 results. The values for userdef37, userdef38, userdef39, userdef40 are checkboxes that are checked or not. 1 being checked and 0 being not checked.

In my end result I need to get the row_id and payment_remaining from query results 2 where the corresponding userdef37, 38, 39 and 40 are equal to 1.

In this example I need 
row_id      payment_remaining
6924954     388.97

because userdef37, userdef38 were both 1.

I think the end result for query 1 results is to try to get it into a table that can be joined on query 2 results like this.

```
task_refno      due_date        selected
252152         02/29/2020       1
252152         03/29/2020       1
252152         04/29/2020       0
252152         NULL             0
```

And try to join on due_date.

I've never had to take row data and turn it into tabular data.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Using MS SQL 17.